# Trouble in change password page in yii application

Tags: php, yii

I want change password at special page.

When i click "Change password" i must go to the password view.

This is code for update view from where i need to go

```
<?php
/* @var $this UserController */
/* @var $model User */

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'User List', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create User', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'View User', 'url'=>array('view', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('label'=>'Change password', 'url'=>array('password', 'id'=>$model->id)),
);
?>

<h1>Change user <?php echo $model->id; ?></h1>

<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

This is my password.php view file

```
<?php
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List user', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create user', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'View user', 'url'=>array('view', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('label'=>'Change user', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
);
?>

<?php
CHtml::beginForm();
CHtml::textField('password');
CHtml::submitButton('Change');
CHtml::endForm();
?>
```

UserController has action actionPassword()

```
public function actionPassword($id) {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $model->password=$_POST['password'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        $this->render('password');
}
```

In example i use this code works fine. But i have error 
http://pastebin.com/XbCwfhRT

All files and folders have root privileges. What i do wrong? Month ago same code works fine and i don't understand what know going wrong.

Comment: Is `$model` being created correctly? Is the value in `$id` valid? How about a `var_dump($model);` to make sure. Also  it is a bad idea to save passwords as clear text.

Comment: i add crypto functions when have fine work without it. id is valid. i have right $model and $id. in url i have right link. but page not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to check if the `$_POST` is set so when action is loaded (before submit)  `$_POST['password']` doesn't exist.

```
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $model->password=$_POST['password'];
    if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}
```

Comment: thanks. but now i have another trouble. If i left    $this->render('password'); I have error http://pastebin.com/GADp9bFV. If i set $this->render('password', array('model'=>$this->loadModel($id))); I have page without form

Comment: ohhh. latest trouble is so cute. i forgot to add "echo" before "CHtml". Now all works fine.